# during Chinese remainder congruence simplify

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

[image]

I don't understand highlighted part, which means I don't know how to simply congruences.

how can 20y1 = 1 (mod3) can be simply 2y1 = 1 (mod 3)

how 2 y1 = 1 (mod3) change to 2y1 = 2 (mod3)

I don't understand every steps....

I only know what a = b (mod 3)

means that b is remainder of a/3 ....

Is there any rules? for it ?

Comment: Please learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It makes your post easier to read and helps other with similar questions find your post.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{array}{r|l}
   20y_1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 & \text{Given} \\
    2y_1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 & \text{Because $20 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.} \\
    4y_1 \equiv 2 \pmod 3 & \text{Multiply both sides by $2$.} \\
     y_1 \equiv 2 \pmod 3 & \text{Because $4 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.} \\
\end{array}

Why is $20 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$?
$\quad$ Because $3$ goes into $20$ six times with a remainder of $2$.
$\quad$ Or because $3$ divides $(20-2)$.

Why multiply both sides by $2$?
$\quad$ Because $\dfrac 12 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$. (See the next question.)

Why is $4 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$?
$\quad$ Because $3$ goes into $4$ one times with a remainder of $1$.
$\quad$ Or because $3$ divides $(4-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

First note
\begin{align}
2^{-1} \equiv 2\mod 3
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
y_1 \equiv2^{-1}*2y_1 \equiv 2^{-1}\ast1 \equiv 2\mod 3.
\end{align}

Edit: Let me explain a bit more.

You start out with the equation
\begin{align}
20y_1 \equiv 1 \mod 3
\end{align}
and you basically want to solve for $y_1$. Of course, if this is just regular old middle school algebra then we would immediately multiply both sides by $20^{-1}$ to get
\begin{align}
y_1 \equiv 20^{-1} \mod 3. 
\end{align}
But then we need to figure out what is $20^{-1}$.

However, the problem could be further simplified if we first reduced $20$ to $2$ since we are in the mod $3$ world to get
\begin{align}
2y_1 \equiv 1 \mod 3 
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
y_1 \equiv 2^{-1} \mod 3. 
\end{align}
Finally, observe
\begin{align}
2*2 \equiv 4 \equiv 1 \mod 3
\end{align}
which means $2^{-1} = 2$. Thus, we have the desired result.

Comment: ...... um ... I dont get it...